# What's up with this reversing bit order function?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm rather ashamed to admit that I don't know as much about bits and bit manipulation as I probably should. I tried to fix that this weekend by writing some 'reverse the order of bits' and 'count the ON bits' functions. I took an example from [here](http://www.c.happycodings.com/Miscellaneous/code28.html) but when I implemented it as below, I found I had to be looping while < 29. If I loop while < 32 (as in the example) Then when I try to print the integer (using a printBits function i've written) I seem to be missing the first 3 bits. This makes no sense to me, can someone help me out?

Thanks for everyone's help, I've added comments to show changes I've made.

```
int reverse(int n)
{
    int r = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 29; i++) //Should be i < 32
    {
        r = (r << 1) + (n & 1); //| instead of + to make it obvious I'm handling bits
        n >>=1;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Here is my printBits function:

```
void printBits(int n)
{
    int mask = 0X10000000; //unsigned int mask = 0X80000000;
    while (mask)
    {
        if (mask & n)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0");
        }
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And a working? reverse function

```
int reverse2(int n)
{
    int r = n;
    int s = sizeof(n) * 7; // int s = (sizeof(n) * 8) -1

    for (n >>= 1; n; n >>=1)
    {
        r <<=1;
        r |= n & 1;
        s--;


    r <<= s;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: remember your loop is zero-based.  so 32 is from 0 to 31...

Comment: Can you post your PrintBits function just in case there's an issue with that too? It might help. :-)

Comment: Also, to follow-up with Tony's comment, this is an integer, a signed integer, so one bit you lose due to storing the sign (+/-). So now the loop is from 0 to 30. And perhaps you lose one more necessary iteration because, for n bits, you need to loop n-1 times. Think about it - how many shifts must you do to reverse 2 bits? 3 bits? etc...

Comment: For fun: __asm__("bswap %0" : "=r" (n) : "0" (n));

Comment: @evilpie If you're talking about the x86 instruction, this doesn't reverse the bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
int mask = 0x10000000;
```

There are two problems here.  You don't have the high bit set, and if you did, it still (probably) wouldn't work, as your compiler would be using arithmetic shift on a signed `int`.

You want to change your mask to:

```
unsigned int mask = 0x80000000;
```

For arithmetic shift, shifting `0x80000000` right will never become zero, as the sign bit will be magically extended into the other bits.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) for more details on arithmetic shift.

Answer (score 5):

```
int mask = 0X10000000;
```

puts a 1 in bit 28. You want `0X80000000`.

Answer (score 3):

Print Bits is wrong, its 0x80000000 not 0x10000000.

```
>>> bin (0x80000000)  
'0b10000000000000000000000000000000'  
>>> bin (0x10000000)  
'0b10000000000000000000000000000'
```

See 0x1... doesnt set the highest bit.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `+`, you should use `|` (bitwise or). And you should use `< 32`.

Comment: `+` and `|` will give the same results here.

Comment: `+` or `|` makes no difference here, and `+` is probably clearer, so why use `|`?

Comment: @Chris Dodd: `|` is clearer. You're dealing with bits, not arithmetics. So use the operators designed for bit manipulation.

Comment: You should use `|` to emphasize that your performing bit-wise operations.

Comment: I still think `+` is clearer as you're adding a single bit, not doing a bitwise operation on the entire word

Answer (score 1):

As written, this will reverse the lower 29 bits of n into r.  The top three bits of n will be left in n (shifted down 29 bits) and not returned.

I would suspect a problem with your printBits function if you see something else.

*edit*

Your printBits function prints the lower 29 bits of n, so it all makes sense.